# In React, how to create a GitHub like navigation system?

Tags: reactjs

When you navigate on GitHub, it like the whole next page is preloaded inside the current page, and then navigate.
So is there a way to render a component in background ? And then insert it in the DOM ? Some component need to fetch some data, 
I would like it to be done in background too.
I'm using react-router-dom and relay for data fetching.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved with the [Transitions](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-patterns.html#transitions) concurrent UI pattern:

> wait for some content to load before transitioning to the new screen

But the React [Concurrent Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html) is quite a complicated topic, still an experimental feature at the time of writing, it needs a special setup before you can start using `<Suspense />` and `useTransition` Hook - please read the updated documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this is exaclty what I'm looking for. I guess I will have to wait to have this feature released :)